# R - Assign special color for lowest value in colorRampPalette

Tags: r, colors, gradient, heatmap

I have a dataframe like this:

```
library(lubridate)
date_list = seq(ymd('2017-01-01'),ymd('2018-12-31'),by='day')

values = sample(0:35, 730, replace=TRUE)
testframe = data.frame(Date = date_list, Value = values)
```

The values are between 0 and 35. I want to create a heatmap with this data with colors from lightblue1 to royalblue. My problem is, that I want to highlight the values that are 0. They should stand out with a red color. So I dont want to have a gradient from 0 to the next numbers, I completely want to seperate 0 from 1. So all 0 should be red and all other values should be colored in a gradient from lightblue1 to royalblue.

I am using a heatmap, that contains the colorRampPalette, the full code is here: [Heatmap Code](https://github.com/cran/makeR/blob/master/R/calendarHeat.R)

When I add `btb<- c("lightblue1", "royalblue")` in line 83 of the code and change the color in line 46 aswell I get the gradient without the red. How can I add now the red color for all 0?

Any suggestions on how I can solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer

In addition to adding the line

```
b2b <- c("lightblue1", "royalblue")
```

you also need to change

```
calendar.pal <- colorRampPalette((col.sty), space = "Lab")
```

to something like

```
calendar.pal1 <- colorRampPalette((col.sty), space = "Lab")
calendar.pal  <- function(n) c("red", calendar.pal1(n-1))
```

Then, we can get the red highlighting you want

```
calendarHeat(date_list, values, color = "b2b", ncolors = 15)
```

[image]

Note that I've decreased the number of colors there. If the `ncolors` value is too high, the red disappears, so you have to watch for that.

### Old Answer

The code you linked was pretty lengthy, so I didn't spend time studying it. Instead, I generate the following solution to your general problem:

First, create a function giving the basic color ramp:

```
foo <- colorRampPalette(c("lightblue1", "royalblue"))
```

Then, create a function that *calls* `foo()` for the color ramp, but modifies it according to your highlight rule here:

```
bar <- function(x) {
    pal <- foo(length(x))
    pal[which(x == 0)] <- "red"
    return(pal)
}
```

I generate data as in your post (setting the seed for reproducibility):

```
library(lubridate)
date_list = seq(ymd('2017-01-01'),ymd('2018-12-31'),by='day')
set.seed(123)
values = sample(0:35, 730, replace=TRUE)
```

And try out the function:

```
plot(date_list, values, col = bar(values), pch = 19)
```

[image]

Comment: Thx, that is what I wanted. Unfortunately I cant get it right in the code. Actually there are only 3 lines that are used for the color. Its line 46 to assign the gradient, line 80-86 and line 127. I tried to add   b2b <- c("lightblue1", "royalblue") #lightblue to royalblue intot he color styles at line 80 and then add from line 85 on:   assign("col.sty", get(color))
  calendar.pal1 <- colorRampPalette((col.sty), space = "Lab")
  calendar.pal <- function(x) {
    pal <- calendar.pal1(length(x))
    pal[which(x == 0)] <- "red"
    return(pal)
  }  That did not help :/

Comment: @Mr.Spock I have a better idea of what you're looking for now. Will update the answer in just a moment.

Comment: No worries, @Mr.Spock -- glad it helped!